# Temporarily disable cache in play framework

Tags: scala, playframework

I am using the built in cache in a scala playframework 2.4 application.

During development, I would like to be able to deactivate the whole cache temporarily.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using play's default cache implementation, which is `EhCache`, you can run your play application with `net.sf.ehcache.disabled=true` in order to turn off the cache. Of course this is not so desirable for automated testing and only applicable to `EhCache` implementation.